# PHP check if it sub url page then redirect to base url

Tags: php, redirect, base-url

I want to redirect user to BASE_URL from sub page/url, something like **from** *www.website.com/page-post-etc* **to** *www.website.com*.

Actually I've loaded sub-page remotely (ajax) via modalbox (bootstrap), and onclick relative url is updating with pushState, but if i hit reload then broken page shows up. So i want to redirect user to base_url instead of landing on broken page.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using a framework or you are working in native code ?

Comment: Thanks for taking interest and helping me. I'm using Wordpress framework. But i haven't included get_header() in single (post) page.